# Selecting from complex nested JSON data in JQ

Tags: json, jq, any

I have JSON data like this:

```
{
  "profiles": {
    "auto_scaler": [
      {
        "auto_scaler_group_name": "myasg0",
        "auto_scaler_group_options": {
          ":availability_zones": ["1a", "1b", "1c"],
          ":max_size": 1,
          ":min_size": 1,
          ":subnets": ["a", "b", "c"],
          ":tags": [
            {":key": "Name", ":value": "app0" },
            {":key": "env", ":value": "dev" },
            {":key": "role", ":value": "app" },
            {":key": "domain", ":value": "example.com" },
            {":key": "fonzi_app", ":value": "true"},
            {":key": "vpc", ":value": "nonprod"}
          ]
        },
        "dns_name": "fonz1"
      },
      {
        "auto_scaler_group_name": "myasg1",
        "auto_scaler_group_options": {
          ":availability_zones": ["1a", "1b", "1c"],
          ":max_size": 1,
          ":min_size": 1,
          ":subnets": ["a", "b", "c"],
          ":tags": [
            {":key": "Name", ":value": "app1" },
            {":key": "env", ":value": "dev" },
            {":key": "role", ":value": "app" },
            {":key": "domain", ":value": "example.com" },
            {":key": "bozo_app", ":value": "true"},
            {":key": "vpc", ":value": "nonprod"}
          ]
        },
        "dns_name": "bozo1"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I want to write a jq query to firstly select the Hash element in the Array at `.profiles.auto_scaler` whose Array of Hashes at `.auto_scaler_group_options.tags` contains Hashes containing a "`:key`" key whose value *contains* "`fonzi`" and a "`:value`" key whose value is *exactly* `true` and then return the value of the key `dns_name`.

In the example, the query would simply return `"fonz1"`.

Does anyone know how to do this, if it is possible, using jq?

Comment: post the final expected result

Comment: Well I already said I want to see {"GGG": "HHH"} returned. I'll update the question to be clearer and use JSON syntax in the response.

Comment: Also, please fix the sample data. Preferably, the Q would include at least one valid JSON example.

Comment: Maybe I have made it more confusing by redacting the AAA/BBB but I want literally and precisely what I said - AAA/BBB/CCC aren't placeholders; they can be literal strings. Anyway, I think I'll make it clearer by un-redacting it a bit.

Comment: Ok, I have rewritten the question using redacted data that is much closer to the real data (which I couldn't share for security reasons).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In brief, yes.

In long:

```
.profiles.auto_scaler[]
| .dns_name as $name
| .auto_scaler_group_options
| select( any(.[":tags"][];
             (.[":key"] | index("fonzi")) and (.[":value"] == "true")) )
| $name
```

The output of the above is:

```
"fonz1"
```

The trick here is to extract the candidate .dns_name before diving more deeply into your "complex nested JSON".

#### An alternative

If your jq does not have `any`, you could (in this particular case) get away without it by replacing the `select` expression above with:

```
 select( .[":tags"][]
         | (.[":key"] | index("fonzi")) and (.[":value"] == "true") )
```

Be warned, though, that the semantics of the two expressions are slightly different.  (Homework exercise: what is the difference?)

If your jq doesn't have `any` and if you want the semantics of `any`, then you could easily roll your own, or simply upgrade :-)

Comment: Thanks so much. Looks like I also need to study the any() function. Well thanks again.

Answer (score -1):

You can lookup JSON in number or ways ,

1. by checking property exists or not
2. by using [property] syntax,
3. 'property' in object syntax

for your case , here's a small sample , further you can lookup on array and see

> containing a "key" key whose value contains EEE and a "value" key
>   whose value is exactly FFF

```
for(var k=0; k < p['AAA']['BBB'].length;k++){  
   console.log(p['AAA']['BBB'][k]) 
}
```

where p is JSON object.

Hope that helps

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear enough, but this is a question about jq.